# Specify ContentSize when creating new ContentVersion in UnitTest

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, contentversion, contentdocument

I used the post: [Test class for contentdocumentlink](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/181963/test-class-for-contentdocumentlink) as a model, however, when I attempt to define my own ContentSize for the ContentVersion document I receive:

> Field is not writable: ContentVersion.ContentSize

```
ContentVersion contentVersion = new ContentVersion(
      Title = 'Penguins',
      PathOnClient = 'Penguins.jpg',
      VersionData = Blob.valueOf('Test Content'),
      IsMajorVersion = true,
      ContentSize = 304088000
    );
    insert contentVersion;
```

In my trigger I'm making decisions predicated on the ContentSize of the file added - if I'm unable to define ContentSize, my code coverage is only 41%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the field is not writable I think you only have three options.

- If the file you are comparing to is small, you can simply create a file of that size. In your case the file size requirement seems too big to do that. That leaves you with two other solutions.
- You can use Test.isRunningTest() to determine if it is a test and test your logic.
- Alternatively, you could use @isTest(SeeAllData=true) and use a real file to test your logic with.

Comment: Ended up using your third suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Ended up going with Kasper's third bullet point and using:

`@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
private class Test_ContentDocumentLink {
    static testMethod void myUnitTest() {

        // uses a testUtility class to pre-define required fields etc. 
        Opportunity opp = TestUtils.CreateOpportunities(1)[0];
        insert opp;
        // not preferred, but defining ContentSize while creating a ContentVersion record resulted in the error "field not writable"

        // a file larger than 304087040 bytes must reside in the org - otherwise nothing will be returned in the query
        List<ContentDocument> documents = [SELECT Id, Title, LatestPublishedVersionId FROM ContentDocument WHERE ContentSize > 304087040 LIMIT 1];
        for (ContentDocument contentDocument: documents){
            //create ContentDocumentLink  record 
            ContentDocumentLink cdl = New ContentDocumentLink();
            cdl.LinkedEntityId = opp.id;
            cdl.ContentDocumentId = contentDocument.Id;
            cdl.shareType = 'V';
            insert cdl;
        }
    }
}`