# ContentSize in Test Class

Tags: unit-test, contentdocument

I am writing a trigger that deletes files/attachments smaller than 5 KB assigned to email messages.

I read on [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/190134/specify-contentsize-when-creating-new-contentversion-in-unittest) post that the field ContentSize on ContentDocumentVersion is not writable.

My question us, is there another way to set the size of a file? any test class without this field will not achieve its goal which is to test the functionality of my code and not just gain code coverage.

The accepted solution btw suggested to upload a file to the system but I prefer to avoid being dependant on real data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to set VersionData on the ContentDocumentVersion

Comment: Your not wrong, but this answer would benefit from a better explanation. Please read about [answer], then [edit] your answer to include more information. I'm looking forward to your future contributions to our network.

Comment: Thank you @mattyo for the suggestion, I did use the solution and it worked:
`VersionData = Blob.valueOf(String-With-More-Than-3000-Characters)`